# Azure Data Factory Copy Tar gzip activity issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are copying data from source as tar.gzip e.g.

https://api.crunchbase.com/bulk/v4/bulk_export.tar.gz?user_key=user_key

The data is zipped as tar.gz

I would like to copy the zipped tar gzips file to sink with the individual csv's. So the result of the copy activity would look like the following in the destination folder:

[image]

At present my source looks like the following:
[image]

And my destination (SINK) looks like the following:

[image]

So, basically I would like to copy a source file which looks like the following:

bulk_export_sample.tar.gz

And is exported / unzipped during the copy activity as the CSVs shown in the image above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used `Compression type` in Source settings.

You need to select Compression type as `TarGZip(.tgz/.tar.gz)` in your Source connections settings. This will unzip files from zipped folder.

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92973/extract-files-from-targz-files-store-in-blob-conta.html